# Read Tokens from config file in Python

Tags: python, file, parsing, twitter, access-token

Im new in the world of Python and i have a question for you:

Im using the Python Twitter Tools for streaming and storing tweets and want to read the Access Tokens from a different file (config.py) with the format..:

```
from twitter import *

WORLD_WOE_ID = 1
ARGENTINA_WOE_ID = 23424747

CONSUMER_KEY = "xxxxxx"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "xxxxx"
ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY = "xxxxx"
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "xxxxx"
```

How can i read this file and parse only the tokens what i need?

I tried to use "file.readline()" but that command brings me the full line (included "CONSUMER_KEY = ..." etc..) and i only need the key between quotation marks :S

Thank you and sorry for my bad English !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply import the variable.

Save this file as `config.py`

Then you can import the consumer key as follows:

```
from config import CONSUMER_KEY

print(CONSUMER_KEY)
>> XXXXXXX
```

Make sure the folder containing these files has an `__init__.py` file in it.

Better practice would be to import it from the folder that it resides in.

```
from folder_name.config import CONSUMER_KEY
```

You can also, import it in the `__init__.py` and then get it with

```
from folder import CONSUMER_KEY
```

Answer (score 2):

@Daniel Lee's answer in terms of importing is correct, however you might consider using environment variables for greater security. Mainly preventing these settings from being committed to source control where they could possibly be viewed by anyone.

If you're running it from the command line you can set them in a file by themselves:

```
# yourfile.sh

WORLD_WOE_ID = 1
ARGENTINA_WOE_ID = 23424747

CONSUMER_KEY = "xxxxxx"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "xxxxx"
ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY = "xxxxx"
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "xxxxx"
```

then before you run your program do:

`source yourfile.sh`

Or you can specify them before you run your program:

`ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY=xxxxx ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET=xxxxx python yourscript.py`

Or if this is web based you'll want to set them in the web server config or WSGI config.

How you get them in your program also depends a bit on how your running it. It most cases you should be able to do

```
from os import environ
token_key = environ.get('ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY')
# etc ...
```

Or for example if you were using Flask:

```
from flask import request
token = request.environ.get('ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY')
```

(i'm sure Django has something similar but I'm less familiar with it)